# Make an APP that runs a code

Tags: applications

Today i started using Linux for the first time in my life and im struggling a lot honestly... so after a while i discovered that running this command:

'sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run'

I can run the xampp control panel

Now I want to make an "app" that runs this exact command but it is not working for some reason.

Someone knows what could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: Note: i tried adding the ".run" at the end of the command too, still the same